# Bootstrap 3.1.1 - What is the .map extension file used for?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I need to upgrade an application I'm working on with the latest Bootstrap version but I'm struggling to figure out what an addition of `bootstrap.css.map` is for?

Do I need to have them to have the css work properly?

I did some search before writing this but since it's relatively new,
I haven't come across any tangible explanations to this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [what are the .map files used for in Bootstrap 3.1?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21504611/what-are-the-map-files-used-for-in-bootstrap-3-1)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It is source map for Firefox and Chrome debuggers.

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/developertools/sourcemaps/

Because the source code is minified/bundled the line numbers do not refer to the orignal files. Source map protocol fixes this, allowing the web debuggers to refer to the original context from where the CSS was generated.

Comment: It was actually coming as a 404 error (which is really bugging me) so would it be O.K. if I just removed that line?

Comment: It is ok to remove it unless you are developing Bootstrap itself.

Comment: Also see: [tag:source-maps]

Comment: from bootstrap.css remove last line or modify accordingly

`/*# sourceMappingURL=bootstrap-css.map */`

Answer (score 2):

you can download it and then place it at the same directory of bootstrap.css file

https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/dist/css/bootstrap.css.map