# Why does my CSS continue to search for code in .less files?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, less

I'm working on an application and styling it right now, however occasionally when I save my style.css file (my temporary change stylesheet before changing it to LESS) I get some messed up elements that were fine before I reuploaded. I made no changes to those elements and I'm 100% sure it's not my CSS, it's also not my browser cache as I've cleared it and reloaded the page with the same issue. I've also added

```
?v=1.0.1
```

onto the end of my link to the stylesheet to trick the browser into believing it's a new one. (Learned that trick on StackOverflow to use with favicons, will give credit when I find where I got it)

It tries to search for the CSS in .LESS files that are non-existent on the web server. Could it be a problem with my bootstrap.css.map file being on the server?

[image: Problem]

**EDIT:** Another thing I can't seem to figure out, is why the CSS actually shows up under the LESS file reference?

Comment: It shows the locations in the LESS files because that's the whole purpose of source maps (the `.map` file); see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21766880/bootstrap-3-1-1-what-is-the-map-extension-file-used-for

Comment: @cvrebert So this would have nothing to do with the stylesheet not overriding the first stylesheet, correct? I ended up fixing it but I don't remember what or how I did it

Comment: Correct. Source maps are purely for debugging. They have no effect on the application of the styles.

Comment: @cvrebert Turns out I was just a little too tired that night.. Had absolutely nothing to do with the broken stylesheets, it was just a fault by me for specifying the wrong media in the link..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found my problem, it turns out I was using the wrong media attribute. For some unknown stupid reason I had set the style.css file to only display for print.. I just removed the entire media attribute to be displayed on all types and it works like a charm.