# not linked to bootstrap.css.map but shows in console

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Following is code i used this is from template when i run this file i see error

```
bootstrap.css.map:1 GET http://localhost:8000/css/bootstrap.css.map 404 (Not Found)
```

but there is no link i made and error shows link is on first line can someone help me where the link is

how do i remove that link can someone help me with this

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Animus A Blogging Category Flat Bootstarp Resposive Website Template | Home :: w3layouts</title>
        <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all">
        <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <meta name="keywords" content="Graphic Responsive web template, Bootstrap Web Templates, Flat Web Templates, Andriod Compatible web template, 
              Smartphone Compatible web template, free webdesigns for Nokia, Samsung, LG, SonyErricsson, Motorola web design" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="contact-top">
            <div class="container">
                <h2>Log in</h2>     
                <div class="contact">
                    <p></p>
                    <div class="contact-down">
                        <div class="contact-right">
                            <div class="col-md-6 contact-info">
                                <form>
                                    <input type="text" name="your name" placeholder="USER NAME" class="input">              
                                    <input type="password" name="your email" placeholder="PASSWORD" class="input">
                                    <div class="clearfix"> </div>
                                    <input type="submit"value="SEND" />
                                </form>                 
                            </div>
                            <div class="clearfix"> </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>  
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21766880/bootstrap-3-1-1-what-is-the-map-extension-file-used-for. You can ignore it or add it manually

Comment: Unless you know you are using it, ignore the error.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's coming from your bootstrap.css file.  You can remove the reference by editing that file and removing the following line from your code:

`/*# sourceMappingURL=bootstrap.css.map */`

Comment: thanks it work's  but i thought its just some txt and it won't link file

Comment: Technically, it isn't actually linked and isn't loading to your website persay.  It's being loaded into Chrome DevTools.

You can read more on what and how to use Source Maps here:

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/developertools/sourcemaps/

It's a very powerful and convenient way to work with code that has been preprocessed, minified, uglified, etc.

Comment: Is there harm in removing sourceMappingURL=bootstrap.css.map?

Answer (score 0):

Source Mapping files should only be used by the Developer Tools.
With Bootstrap you can disable the source map if you like or just ignore the 404 for any .css.map when using the Dev Tools.

If you want to use the Dev Tools for Debugging or want to have more 'completeness' to your code add the .css.map file available from Bootstrap along side the .css file.

Reference: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/css-preprocessors

Other similar questions: [what are the .map files used for in Bootstrap 3.1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21504611/what-are-the-map-files-used-for-in-bootstrap-3-1)

Answer (score 0):

Either you can remove

`/*# sourceMappingURL=bootstrap.css.map */

as mentioned by @xengravity or you can download bootstrap.css.map file of your bootstrap version and add it in your directory.